# Empty Azure Active Directory Applications from recycle bin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Active Directory Application that generates other Azure Active Directory Applications. The thing is that I reached out the limit of 250 applications and I can't create more.

Although I've done a clean up. The Applications are still in the recycle bin and I can't figure out how to remove them from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assume you were using the Azure AD Graph REST to delete the applications. When you using the rest please ensure that deleting operation was executed successfully. For example, the response of deleting application should be return `HTTP 204`.

In-addition, to delete the application we should use the object id of application instead of application id like figure below:
[image]

And then we can delete the application using the Azure AD Graph REST like below:

```
DELETE: https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/{objectId}?api-version=1.6
```

Here is the result figure for your reference:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does MSFT provide some sort of operation to do a DELETE ALL? I have few Applications and delete one by one seems a bit cumbersome..

Comment: No, there is no such REST. However, as a workaround, you can write a program to retrieve all the application and delete it based on the requirement.